# Functionall approach to error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this snippet here: http://www.nodewiz.biz/nodejs-error-handling-pattern/

It supposed to handle errors better than normal way in node.js. But I fail to understand **how it works and why it is better** than plain `if(err)`?

---

Functional Approach

An example using the Express.js feramework, define a function that returns an error handler:

```
function error(res,next) {
    return function( err, result ) {
        if( err ) {
            res.writeHead(500); res.end(); console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            next(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to do this;

```
app.get('/foo', function(req,res) {
    db.query('sql', error(res, function(result) {
        // use result
    }));
});
```

Covering this method only as an example, do not use this method for production code, unless you actually handle the error properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"It supposed to handle errors better than normal way in node.js. But I fail to understand how it works..."*

How it works is that it receives the `res` object and a function (provided by you) that gets invoked if the result was successful.

It then returns a function that is passed to `db.query()` as the callback. So that callback actually receives the `err` and `result`.

If it finds an `err`, it handles sending the appropriate `500` response for you. If it doesn't find an error, it invokes the function you provided passing it the `result`. That way you know that if the function you provided runs, it was because there was no error.

---

> *"...and why it is better than plain if(err)?"*

It isn't better. It's just different. It is nice if the error handling will always be the same in that you can update it in one spot, and any code that uses it will benefit from the update.

However, a simple function abstraction could do the same.

```
function error(res, err) {
    if( err ) {
        res.writeHead(500); res.end(); console.log(err);
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Which allows you to do this;

```
app.get('/foo', function(req,res) {
    db.query('sql', function(err, result) {
        if (error(res, err))
            return;

        // use the result
    }));
});
```

Comment: The "simple function abstraction" won't work as-is unless you define that error() function inside each route callback, which wouldn't be very pretty. The reason being that it does not have access to the `res` object, that's why the original error() had it passed in.

Comment: @mscdex: I just forgot to define and pass the `res`. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: you could put the error handler in a module ie under the models folder and than import it in all your models so you've got a single error handler for all models.

Comment: @Whisher: Good point. Mostly was just giving a demo of an alternative to the functional approach described in the question.